# Control development boards from web interface

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, beagleboard, remote-control

I have multiple Raspberry Pi/ Beagle Board/ Panda boards connects to my web server (clouding). Then I want to my clients control the board's GPIO from web interface. I have read many examples on the Internet but in those example the web server is inside every boards.

So, Could anyone help me to use just 1 web server(clouding) outside all of boards to control board's GPIO? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NexusDataLink](http://nexusdatalink.com) to get your boards connected. This data communication framework allows one to link several devices or systems - the server process may run anywhere. Optionally a REST interface is generated per linked device based on an XML file.